# Ubuntu: PHP cannot find memcached

Tags: php, ubuntu, memcached

This is my first introduction with PHP + Memcached on Ubuntu.
I already did Redis and fully understand Memcached. I installed it successfully, connected with it and successfully executed commands like set/get.

I followed this tutorial to install everything: [digitalocean.com (*how to install and use memcache on ubuntu 14.04*)](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-memcache-on-ubuntu-14-04)

The problems I'm facing is that `phpinfo()` is not showing any information about Memcached.

I understand I need to add this in my php.ini file.:

```
extension=memcache.so
```

I tried to add the extension line in following files, restarted server and still no information.

```
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
/etc/php5/cli/php.ini
```

If I try to execute the following code, I get

> Fatal error: class Memcache not found'

```
$memcache = new Memcache;
$memcache->connect('localhost', 11211) or die ("Could not connect");
```

I also want to know where "memcache.so" exists.

Comment: do you have any errors in the php/apache logs that might be related to this? Depending on your configuration, it might be that PHP works, even despite that the module could not be loaded (e.g. wrong path or wrong ABI).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

```
$memcache = new Memcached;
```

instead of

```
$memcache = new Memcache;
```

Comment: Nothing happened, the error is still same. PHP is not able to find memcached, that is why it does not show any information in phpinfo()

Answer (score 0):

```
$memcache = new \Memcache;

$memcache->connect('localhost', 11211) or die ("Connection problem");
```

And in Terminal check "netstat -ltupn"

What happen on 11211 port.

Comment: Nothing happened, the error is still same. PHP is not able to find memcached, that is why it does not show any information in phpinfo()

Answer (score 0):

on Ubuntu install memcache:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-memcache php5-memcached
```

Answer (score 0):

Server reboot did the trick, nothing worked for me as well. Hope there is better solution without rebooting the server.